# Calculating mark-to-market P&L in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the 5 minute mark to market P&L for a list of trades.

The trades are stored in a data frame, which is different from the data frame for the market rates.

Hence when obtaining the rate 5 minutes after execution, i'm using a for loop.

This means the process is very slow when the number of trades and the amount of rates grow over a period time.

```
trades_df <- 
       data.frame( 
             "instrument" = c('XAUUSD','AUDUSD','EURUSD','XAUUSD'), 
             "direction" = c('BUY','SELL','SELL','BUY'), 
             "deal_rate" = c('2000.65','0.6855','1.2456','2050.67'),
             "amount" = c('500','1000000','3000000','1000'), 
             "execution_time" = c('2023-06-02 12:15:18','2023-06-03 16:15:18','2023-07-02 12:30:18','2023-06-04 03:15:27')
         ) 

rates_df <- 
  data.frame( 
    "instrument" = c('XAUUSD','AUDUSD','EURUSD','XAUUSD','AUDUSD','EURUSD', 'XAUUSD','AUDUSD','EURUSD'), 
    "rate" = c('2000.5','0.6955','1.26','2000.6','0.695','1.2602','2000.7','0.6965','1.2603'), 
    "rate_time" = c('2023-06-02 12:15:00','2023-06-02 12:15:00','2023-06-02 12:15:00','2023-06-02 12:15:01','2023-06-02 12:15:01','2023-06-02 12:15:01','2023-06-02 12:15:02','2023-06-02 12:15:02','2023-06-02 12:15:02')
  ) 

for (i in (1:nrow(trades_df))) {
  
  trades_df[i,]$mtm_rate <- rates_df %>% group_by(instrument) %>% filter(rate_time >= trades_df[i,]$execution_time + 5*60)
  
}

trades_df <- trades_df %>%
  mutate(
    PnL = ifelse(direction == "BUY", (mtm_rate - deal_rate) * amount, (deal_rate - mtm_rate) * amount)
  )
```

Is there faster way to calculate this? Is it possible to be done in a vectorized way?

I appreciate any guidance.

Thank you.

Comment: The code doesn't run with the sample data as provided, but I presume this could be done more efficiently using a non-equi join, something like `trades_df |> left_join(rates_df |> select(mtm_rate = rate, instrument, rate_time, rate_time_plus5 = rate_time + 5*60), join_by(instrument, closest(execution_time >= rate_time), execution_time < rate_time_plus5))`

Comment: I've updated the code in the for loop that cause the error. I have tried the following code but encounter error: object 'rate_time' not found in the "rate_time + 5*60". `rates_df |> select(mtm_rate = rate, instrument, rate_time, rate_time_plus5 = rate_time + 5*60)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be much faster as a non-equi join, once we convert the timestamps to datetime format:

```
library(dplyr)
rates_df$rate_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(rates_df$rate_time)
trades_df$execution_time = lubridate::ymd_hms(trades_df$execution_time)

trades_df |> 
  left_join(transmute(rates_df, mtm_rate = rate, instrument, rate_time,
                      rate_time_plus5 = rate_time + 5*60), 
            join_by(instrument, 
                    closest(execution_time >= rate_time), 
                    execution_time < rate_time_plus5))
```

Result

```
  instrument direction deal_rate  amount      execution_time mtm_rate           rate_time     rate_time_plus5
1     XAUUSD       BUY   2000.65     500 2023-06-02 12:15:18   2000.7 2023-06-02 12:15:02 2023-06-02 12:20:02
2     AUDUSD      SELL    0.6855 1000000 2023-06-03 16:15:18     <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
3     EURUSD      SELL    1.2456 3000000 2023-07-02 12:30:18     <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
4     XAUUSD       BUY   2050.67    1000 2023-06-04 03:15:27     <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
```